# How do you make an imageview larger in ListView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

I have a problem with the ListView. I want to make the image larger in ListView.
I tried to set android:layout_height="match_parent" but it dont work :(

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <SquaredFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/vImageRoot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivFeedCenter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/img_feed_center_2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </SquaredFrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivFeedBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnLike"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_feed_action"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_heart_small_blue" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_heart_small_blue" />

            <TextSwitcher
                android:id="@+id/tsLikesCounter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:inAnimation="@anim/slide_in_likes_counter"
                android:outAnimation="@anim/slide_out_likes_counter">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="123 likes"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_like_counter" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_like_counter" />
            </TextSwitcher>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I would like that it looks
but it looks like

Sorry for my bad English :)
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ImageView  
        android:scaleType = "centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/ivFeedCenter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/img_feed_center_2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```